# Find one attribute in XML File with linq.XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, attributes

i want to find the value of an Attribute in our XML-FIle.

For Example, here our XML Document:

```
<PROJECT_DOCUMENTS>
   <DOCUMENT isFile="YES" isLink="YES" type="Risk Action List (combined)" path="path" showFile="" showFolder="YES" FilePath="" FolderPath="" />
   <DOCUMENT isFile="YES" isLink="NO" type="ASPICE-Action List" path="path" showFile="" showFolder="YES" FilePath="" FolderPath="path" />
</PROJECT_DOCUMENTS>
```

I want the value of path = " .... bla ..." were the type is ASPICE-Action List.

Here my code with i generated:

```
 XElement elementToChange = (from c in getFileFromXML.Element("PROJECT_DOCUMENTS")
                                        .Elements("DOCUMENT")
                                        where("type"== "ASPICE-Action List")
                                        select c).Single().Element("path");
```

But i dont get the infomation. I think the type == Aspice-Action list doesn´t work.

Can anyone help me to solve my Problem ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `path` attribute values you can use next code which manipulate with [`Attribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) method for attributes of element:

```
var elementsToChange = from c in getFileFromXML.Element("PROJECT_DOCUMENTS").Elements("DOCUMENT")
                where c.Attribute("type")?.Value == "ASPICE-Action List" )
                select c.Attribute("path").Value;
```

To retrieve whole elements use next code or add [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) to the end for your tasks:

```
var elementsToChange = from c in getFileFromXML.Element("PROJECT_DOCUMENTS").Elements("DOCUMENT")
                where c.Attribute("type")?.Value == "ASPICE-Action List" )
                select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the same using the code below:

```
from c in getFileFromXML.Elements("DOCUMENT")
where "ASPICE-Action List" == c.Attribute("type").Value
select c;
```